# Exibir Imagem Externa ao Server p:graphicImage

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou usando desta forma: XHTML:

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{emitenteBean.myImage}"
```

Bean:

```
private StreamedContent myImage;  

try {  
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/Users/user/files/minhaImg.jpg");  
myImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(fileInputStream, "image/jpeg");  

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {  
  System.out.println("ERRO AO CONVERTER IMG.");  
}
```

Não exibe a imagem e não apresenta erro.

Comment: Ótimo. Vou testar!

Comment: você utiliza tomcat certo? pelo que me lembro de posts anteriores, se sim você poderia utilizar aqueles diretórios virtuais, é um pouco chato de configurar a primeira vez, mas fica elegante de utilizar no código depois, ex: [diretório virtual](https://gist.github.com/dilnei/4c9b5ad8865b8c045f7b)  [exibir-imagem-fora-do-diretorio-da-aplicacao--jsf-e-primefac‌​es](http://respostas.guj.com.br/36049-exibir-imagem-fora-do-diretorio-da-aplicacao--jsf-e-primefaces--) – Dilnei Cunha

Comment: Creio que estou fazendo algo errado. A Imagem não é exibida:

Comment: Veja a abaixo o que fiz, mas o erro continua.

Answer (score 0):

Arquivo no Tomcat: `openfiscal#uploadsopenfiscal.xml`

Conteudo Aquivo Tomcat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" docBase="/Users/jeremias/Downloads/uploadsopenfiscal" path="/arquivosupload">
  <Resource auth="Container" factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" name="BeanManager" type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"/>
</Context>
```

getCaminhoImagem: `"../arquivosupload/cliente/minhaImage.jpg"`

XHTML: `<p:graphicImage value="#{emitenteBean.emitente.logo.caminhoImagem}"`

No Chrome: `src="../arquivosupload/cliente/minhaImage.jpg?pfdrid_c=false&uid=89c637b7-24a1-439f-a89d-a3e17afe7399"`

Answer (score 0):

Conseguiu resolver somente mapeando pelo Eclipse direto no tomcat. Minha duvida veio como levo isto pra produção já que mapeei o diretório por dentro do eclipse. Além do arquivo gerado dentro do Catalina/localhost como informado outro post.

Comment: O arquivo XML criado é quem define o path, adicionando ele no server não precisa mais nada, ja vai funcionar, mas qualquer coisa me comunica que a gente ajusta.

Comment: O Post abaixo mostra o que fiz, mas mesmo assim não exibia a imagem, somente após mapear no tomcat pelo eclipse começou a exibir.

Comment: hummm, não entendi porque vc usou ../ para navegar um diretorio para trás, vc viu no meu gist como eu uso? eu apenas passo o diretório mapeado,  quando a gente usa IDE's as vezes temos que ter cuidado com esses arquivos de configuração pois geralmente ela cria cache desses arquivos, no eclipse ele cria uma pasta serve dentro da workspace, no netbeans se o tomcat é aquele embedded que vem com ele vc precisa acessar caso windows /appData/roamming/Netbeans/config/.... não lembro todo caminho porque não uso windows mas é ali dentro que fica as config,

Comment: mas se você adiciona o servidor(falando sempre do tomcat) as configs ficam nele próprio, então talvez algo ainda não esteja bem configurado.

Se o diretório virtual ficou criado certinho você acessa ele pela url, ex: http://localhost:8080/images/suaImagem.jpg

Comment: Também é possivel ver o diretŕoio virtual criado  pelo managerApp do tomcat, logo abaixo onde ficam od deploy.

Comment: O Tomcat é o Zip que baixo e depois add ao Eclipse. A utilização do /../ foi porque pelo Chrome no código gerado ele estava concatenando localhost:8080/NomeProjeto/PastaIMG/imagem.jpg. Tambem não estava acesso direto como você citou. Fiz a configuração em outra maquina e da mesma forma ele só funcionou após informar pelo próprio eclipse. Somente colocando o arquivo como você citou ele não funcionou. Estou iniciando e parando o Server pelo eclipse.

Comment: Outra duvida que fiquei, foi que informo o diretório para salvar as imagens, no caso de um server de hospedagem como eu faria isto? Da mesma forma?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47047/discussion-between-dilnei-cunha-and-jeremias-santos).